# Java: Compare loaded jars on local machine and environment

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, packaging, dependency-management

I've faced problem when something going wrong on remote environment, whereas on localhost all works correct. After some googling I consider that it's caused by maven packaging specific or some jar-versions mismatch. I suppose that some jar file isn't loaded on environment for some reasons.

**Question:** How can I check which libraries match and which not on localhost and environment? For example write the whole jars list to the file on application start on both environments. Is that possible?

**Update:**

In log of `mvn clean install` I've found:

> Including com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.5 in the
>   shaded jar

My problems are linked exactly with the multipart. Is that the reason? But again, the same log appears on localhost too.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to correct your `pom.xml` file. To avoid such error keep your version at properties tag. Look at `${spring.version}` in below example.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

May be [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345970/1115584) answer will help you.

Comment: not in my case. My dependencies are:: `com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.5`, `com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:1.5` and `com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client:1.1-m02`. There is no 1.5 version for the last one.